# PHP - GET request works in Postman, but not with cUrl

Tags: php, api, curl, get

There's a free weather API in my country that I want to use to get rain data. The request is simple https://apitempo.inmet.gov.br/estacao/2021-05-03/2021-05-06/A826 and there's no authentication. If I try the request using Postman, my browser or AJAX, it works fine and I get the results I need. However, using cURL, I get nothing.

Here's the PHP code that I tried:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://apitempo.inmet.gov.br/estacao/2021-05-03/2021-05-06/A826',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I have the cURL.dll installed and tested in another server, but it didn't work.

Is there a problem with the code or is it the API that blocks PHP requests?

Comment: What `http code` do you get back? Any errors in your `curl_error`? With `I get nothing.` we can't do much there could be many reasons wy you dont get the expected returned values. Maybe the server asume your a bot because of the wrong header values and block your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its look like this website looking for user-agent header.
try this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://apitempo.inmet.gov.br/estacao/2021-05-03/2021-05-06/A826',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'User-Agent: something'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```